# Keyboard has a strange software related Issue

Tags: keyboard

I have an Issue wIth my Apple keyboard where the "I" key does not work In lowercase mode.
When I checked usIng the keyboard vIewer, It shows that the lower case "I" Is trIggerIng a  double ⌘ (command key)
I have trIed a dIfferent keyboard (I use an apple bluetooth keyboard and have trIed replacIng It as well as usIng a separate USB keyboard)
I have an IMAC 10,1 runnIng OS X 10.6.8
Any and all advIce welcomed

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause of one key not working is that it has been set as the trigger for something, most often either Speech Recognition or Text to Speech.  Double check the settings in your system preferences/speech.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I have checked the unIversal access settIngs and all of these are dIsabled so not the cause of the problem

Comment: Tom, THANK YOU!!!  I went back in to check for the tenth time that it was NOT a setting in universal access and I noticed the "speech" icon nearby on the basis of your post.  In that menu there was indeed a setting for speech on use of the "i" key, even though the universal access settings were deactivated.
I thought I was going mad trying to figure this one out.  THANK YOU